# How to manage ProgressDialog spinner [android]

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm having a problem in ProgressDialog. I'm a beginner, i'm unable to understand it's working.Here is my first Activity code-

```
 public class AddFriend extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btSend, btPending;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private ProgressCircle progressBar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addfriend);
    initializeVar();
    btSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btPending.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void initializeVar() {
    System.out.println("Initializing variables");
    btSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSend);
    btPending = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPending);
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    progressBar = new ProgressCircle();
   // progressBar.start(v.getContext());
    System.out.println("status=" + progressBarStatus);
    progressBarStatus= click(v);
    System.out.println("status after=" + progressBarStatus);
    if (progressBarStatus == 1) {
        progressBar.stop();
    }
}

public int click(View v) {
    int status=10;
    //ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddFriend.this,"wait","Processin",true);
    progressBar.start(v.getContext());
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btSend:
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddFriend.this, AddFriendSend.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            status=1;
            break;
        case R.id.btPending:
            ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection();
            ArrayList<String> pending;
            pending = sc.pendingRequest(v);
            int size = pending.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("No Pending Request");
                alert.show();
                status=1;
            } else {
                String[] arr = new String[size];
                arr = pending.toArray(arr);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(AddFriend.this, PendingRequest.class).putExtra("pending", arr);
                startActivity(intent1);
                status=1;
            }

            break;
    }
    while(status!=1)
    {}
    return 1;
}}
```

Here is ProgressCircle class:-

```
public class ProgressCircle {
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    public void start(Context context) {
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("Processing...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        System.out.println("process Circle");
        progressBar.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (progressBar != null) {
            System.out.println("process stop");
            progressBar.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

This is my addfriend.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/btSend"
    android:text="Send a new Request"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/btPending"
    android:text="Pending Requests"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

On executing above code I'm not getting any progress dialog. Although program is calling to start() and stop() methods. Somebody Please Help.
I just want that whenever onClick() execute, a processing circle should be shown untill code in click() method execute completely.

Answer (score 0):

your problem above is that you are creating the ProgressBar but you are not adding it to your layout.

Add a ProgressBar to your layout below the buttons (doesnt really matter where).
Make sure you set an id on the ProgressBar.

Then in onInitializeVar() you need to initialize your ProgressBar in the same way that you are initializing your buttons.